# How do i change the output of "uname -m"

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, architecture

I am trying to execute this shell script - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oneindex/script/master/gclone.sh

This shell script checks for `uname -m` output and doesn't like it ( i.e. aarch64 ).

```
xd003@localhost:~$ uname -m
aarch64
xd003@localhost:~$
```

I want to change the `uname -m` output from `aarch64` to `arm64` so that it bypasses this check in the shell script and execute properly.

Comment: You are on an architecture that isn't supported. If you change the script (which would be easier than changing the output of `uname`) to just set `BINTAG=Linux_arm64` instead of running that `case` statement, you will likely download something that isn't compatible with your machine.

Comment: @Kusalananda i am almost sure that it will work because this shell script is a very slightly modded version of something that works pretty great . I am not so good with shell script hence was looking to just spoof the uname -m output else i would have edited script myself.    Can you make a del.dog of this  script with arm64 installation and the uname check removed ?

Comment: Just remove the `case ... esac` statement and replace it with `BINTAG=Linux_arm64`.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you , i successfully executed the script and got it working by setting bintag as arm64 , ( it was the closest to aarch64 hence my best bet )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it happens to be a `bash` script (despite the `.sh` extension), you can always do (within `bash`):

```
uname()
  if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = -m ]; then
    echo arm64
  else
    command uname "$@"
  fi

export -f uname

gclone.sh
```

That is, replace `uname` with an exported function that outputs what you want when passed a `-m` argument.